# What's that which make something insentient and other sentient?

Tags: philosophy, tantra, kashmiri-shaivism, consciousness

Consciosness is ever present everywhere. There is no place where it is not! So on what basis something becomes insentient & other sentient according to Kashmiri Shaivism or Tantra?

Comment: duplicate. I'll find duplicate.

Comment: Your comment is stale now. @Swami It **was** duplicate, not **is**. 

Comment: In at least two of the sciences, Biology & Psychology, consciousness requires self awareness to become sentience. There is ongoing argument about what constitutes self awareness - especially when trying to determine if a nonhuman species is or is not sentient. But in 50 years of personal & professional involvement with both, that defining characteristic remains constant. No self awareness, not sentient. That's not a scriptural reference, it's science.